# Angularjs on-change not firing in select due to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the styled select Jquery plugin, there is a conflict with it the select tag and the angular ng-change directive, it refuse to fire an event to the function defined in the controller in angular, when i remove jquery it works but I'm left with an ugly select. how to i tell angular that a option has been chosen? my code is super simple and works if i remove JQuery.

```
    <select ng-model="industry" ng-change="test()">
        <option value="">fintech</option>
        <option value="aye">gaming</option>
        <option value="eh">marketing</option>
        <option value="ooh">enterprise</option>
    </select>

    $scope.test = function () {
       alert("test");
    }
```

Comment: You can always set a `watch` on `industry`, i.e. `$scope.watch('industry', test);`.

Comment: I suggest writing a directive that wraps jQuery functionality. Inside directive you can either set a $watch on as @jperezov suggested, and call some function you will pass, or use any way that jQuery plugin gives you for this task and then call that function you pass. That gives you little better code reusability.